# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'float'

Tags: python, python-3.x

Сервер:

```
import socket
from random import random as rand

def b(mystring):
    return bytes(mystring, 'utf-8')
def bc(mystring):
    return mystring.decode('utf-8')

sock = socket.socket()
sock.bind(('', 9090))
sock.listen(0)

conn, addr = sock.accept()

while True:
    data = bc(conn.recv(1024))
    if not data:
        break
    elif data=="S":conn.send(rand())  # TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'float'
```

Клиент:

```
import socket

def b(mystring):
    return bytes(mystring, 'utf-8')
def bc(mysteing):
    return mystring.decode('utf-8')

sock = socket.socket()
sock.connect(('localhost', 9090))
sock.send(b("S"))

data = sock.recv(1024)
sock.close()

print(data)
```

Ума не приложу, где я допустил ошибку. Сижу в ступоре.
Такая ошибка на 19 линии:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Арам\PycharmProjects\Towns\main.py", line 19, in <module>
elif data=="S":conn.send(rand())
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'float'
```

Comment: Сервер - https://pastebin.com/DN5HCFYW
Клиент -  https://pastebin.com/Th3cxecJ

Comment: Код надо прикладывать текстом, а не картинками.

Comment: Я в комментариях отправил код, в тексте вопроса есть на это ограничения. Тем более, я полагаю, что решение банально, и картинок будет достаточно.

Comment: Картинки не очень то удобно смотреть. Текста не так много, он спокойно должен поместиться в вопрос. Если это не возможно, воспользуйтесь сторонними серверами хранения кода. Если кто из пользователей решить протестировать ваш код, чтобы попытаться решить вашу проблему на прямую, то у него просто не будет такой возможности.

Comment: Повторюсь: а выложил ссылки на pastebin в комментариях, в них код.
В посте можно разместить только одну ссылку, если нет более 10 очков репутации.

Comment: @Арам, код должен быть текстом прямо в вопросе (не ссылками, не скриншотами, а текстом). Собственно, я его сам уже добавил.

Answer (score 3):

Метод `conn.send()` должен принимать байты (тип `bytes` или `bytearray`), а `random()` возвращает число с плавающей точкой. Чтобы отправить число, нужно сначала его преобразовать в байты. Для простоты (чтобы на вашем варианте клиента получить читаемый вариант) преобразуем число в строку, а ее уже преобразуем в байты:

```
str(rand()).encode()  # получим что-то похожее на b'0.9683099386758524'
```

А дальше уже эти байты отправляем клиенту:

```
conn.send(str(rand()).encode())
```

Вообще лучше передавать числа с плавающей точкой в "машинном" виде, тогда число передастся без потерь (в частности, без округления при переводе в строковый вид). Для этого можно воспользоваться модулем [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html):

```
import struct

...

conn.send(struct.pack('<d', rand()))  # Кодируем в байты как double с порядком байт little-endian
```

На клиенте эти байты нужно наоборот распаковать в объект:

```
print(struct.unpack('<d', data))
```